# PDF with digital signature pfx / p12

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, wkhtmltopdf, signature

I couldn't find in the questions a tool that adds digital signatures to a .pdf file via the linux command.

I need a tool that adds digital certificate to .df files

I have the .pfx certificate

Comment: For software recommendation please use [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Not sure about command line tool but we have Signer.Digital.Webserver developed on .NET Core which also works on Linux and provides [REST API for PDF Signing](https://help.signer.digital/signer_digital_webserver_and_rest_api.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out : https://github.com/jmarxuach/BatchPDFSign

BatchPDFSign is a jar command line to sign PDF file with a PKCS12 certificate.

To use it you need a PKCS12 certificate. It should be a .pfx file. The password for the .pfx and a PDF file to sign.